# Particular Solution of a Fourier Transform.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, fourier-transform

I'm stuck on the following problem and could use a hint on what to do next.

> Consider
> $$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = k \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + Q(x,t) $$
> $$ -\infty < x < \infty \ ,\ u(x,0)=f(x) $$
>
> (a) Show that a particular solution for the Fourier transform $ \bar U $ is
> $$ \bar U = e^{-kw^2t} \int_0^t \bar Q(\omega,\tau)e^{k\omega ^2 \tau}d\tau $$
>
> (b) Determine $ \bar U $
>
> (c) Solve for $u(x,t)$ in the simplest form possible.

Here's my attempt for part (a).

Let $ \ \ \bar U (\omega,t) = FT(u(x,t)) \  , \ \bar Q (\omega, t) = FT(Q(x,t)) \ \ $
such that
$$ FT \big ( \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \big) = FT\big( k \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + Q(x,t) \big) $$
$$ \Rightarrow \frac{\partial \bar U}{\partial t} = k \ FT \big( \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \big) + FT\big(Q(x,t) \big) $$
$$ = \ -k\omega ^2 \bar U \ + \ \bar Q  $$

This is where I'm stuck. I'm not seeing the next step that leads to the particular solution asked for in part (a). I believe I have ideas on how to solve (b) and (c), but I can't do so without solving part (a) first.

Any hints would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have been given the form of $\bar{U}$ in the problem and have only been asked to verify that it is a particular solution, you can just check that the $\bar{U}$ solves the ODE.

Rewrite 
$$
\bar{U}(\omega,t) = \int_0^t e^{k \omega^2 (\tau-t)} \bar{Q}(\omega,\tau) d\tau.
$$
Then 
$$
\partial_t \bar{U}(\omega,t) = e^{-k \omega^2 t} e^{k \omega^2 t}  \bar{Q}(\omega,t) -k \omega^2 e^{-k \omega^2 t} \int_0^t e^{k \omega^2 \tau} \bar{Q}(\omega,\tau) d\tau  \\
= \bar{Q}(\omega,t) - k \omega^2 \bar{U}(\omega,t),
$$
and so $\bar{U}$ is a particular solution the ODE in question.

Now, if you want to know *where* this particular solution comes from, then what you want is "the method of variation of parameters" or "Duhamel's principle."  Actually, we can give a quick proof here.  If we want to solve
$$
f'(t) = a f(t) + g(t)
$$
then we multiply by $e^{-at}$ and rewrite as
$$
(e^{-at} f(t))' = e^{-at} f'(t) -a e^{-at} f(t) = e^{-at} g(t),
$$
and now we simply integrate
$$
e^{-at} f(t) - f(0) = \int_0^t e^{-a \tau} g(\tau) d\tau
$$
and hence
$$
f(t) = f(0) e^{at} + e^{at} \int_0^t e^{-a \tau} g(\tau) d\tau.
$$
This is actually the general solution.  The particular solution comes from ignoring the $f(0)$ term.

Comment: (+1) Great answer, it details what needs to be done without explicitly providing the answer.

Comment: Thank you, @Glitch. That helps a lot, I'll be working on the problem later today and will post my solution once I figure it out.

Comment: You helped me very much with this, thank you!! Very good explanation as well